# dojo toolkit - Enhanced Grid - can we have cell border?

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid

Can I have cell borders (using dojo / js code without changing the css property - .dojoxGridCell) programmatically.

Comment: Did you look into dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid API? there are ways to change CSS. Also always try to post the code that you have tried and then ask for suggestion.

Comment: I've tried few things. But no luck.

Comment: can you post what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

If you have setup your Grid programmaticaly you can use the "style" Option to change the layout of the grid for example.

```
          YourGrid = new EnhancedGrid({
                    id: 'YourGridId',
                    store: YourStore,
                    style: "width:500pt;height:200pt;",
                    structure: layoutYourGridsName,
                    rowSelector: '20px',
                    keepSelection: false,
                    plugins: {
                        indirectSelection: IndirectSelectionSettings,
                        filter: Filtersettings,
                        pagination: PaginationSettings,
                        exporter: true
                    }
                });
```